# Type-safe way to get embedded resource content in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, resources

I'm using **.NET Core 3 preview 6** and **Visual Studio 2019 16.2** for creating WinForms application.

In .NET Framework I used type-safe mechanism to load resources, something like that:

```
this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = global::MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.Image1;
this.textBox1.Text = global::MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.Script1;
```

But in .NET Core 3 I must write special helper class with several methods:

```
public static class EmbeddedResource
{
    public static Image GetImage(String resourceName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = typeof(EmbeddedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                return Image.FromStream(stream);
        }

        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to read Embedded Resource {resourceName}");
        }
    }

    public static String GetString(String resourceName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = typeof(EmbeddedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to read Embedded Resource {resourceName}");
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = EmbeddedResource.GetImage("MyNamespace.Image1.jpg");
this.textBox1.Text = EmbeddedResource.GetString("MyNamespace.Script1.sql");
```

Is there a better way (e. g. strictly-typed and **resourceName** error-safe) to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 16.2 Has design-time support for `Resx` file for Windows Forms .NET Core Projects. It is the same feature that is supported in previous versions of Visual Studio for Windows Forms classic .NET projects.

It means you can:

1. Add New Item → Choose *Resources File* and set a name like `Resources.Resx` and press *Add*. The file will be opened in design mode. (Later to open it in design mode, just double click on it.)
2. Add an image to the designer by dragging an image file and dropping it into the designer. You can also add the image by click on *Add Resource* tool strip drop down button and choosing *Add Existing File ...*.

Then the image will be accessible using a property which has the same name as the image. For example I created a `Properties` folder and created `Resources.Resx` under that folder, then added `MyImage.jpg` to the resource file, the I could use it this way:

```
this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.MyImage;
```

**Note - Create default Resource file for the project in Properties folder**

1. Right click on Project → Choose *Properties*
2. In project properties window, choose *Resources* (left side, bottom of the list).
3. At the center, you will see a link *This project does not contain a default resources file. Click here to create one.* Click on the link and it will create a `Resources.Resx` file under `Properties` folder for your project.

Comment: Wow, excellent. There is only one feature that Visual Studio 2019 lacks - WinForms Designer for .NET Core :)

Comment: It's in the [roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/roadmap.md).

Comment: Yes, I know it. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting `..\\Resource\\webpages.txt;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;utf-8` instead of the actual content. It works on windows

Comment: @Toolkit Sorry, couldn't get it.  If you have found an issue with WinForms .NET Core, you can file it here: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues

Comment: the line `var someVar = Properties.Resources.someResource;` works on Windows. On Linux it doesn't get the file content but `..\\Resource\\webpages.txt;System.String, mscorlib....`